# Magento -SQL 2002 errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, magento-1.7

I have a magento website on EC2 Large instance, with database on RDS which again is a large instance.
Now,
1. I have a maximum of 25 people traffic on website.
2. I am facing the below sql error on timely basis , it appears after sometimes 6-7 hours or sometimes after a day, can anyone help me with this?
3. To get rid of this error I restart the services and it returns to normal, but then after sometime this error again pops up!

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Trace:

```
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some database connectivity error. Check the local,xml file for database connectivity settings. Is your database on the same server otherwise use socket

Comment: No, Its hosted on RDS!! Ever since I moved the database from server to RDS i have been facing this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem on RDS instance. Check connectivity through separate file on the same server.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```